# Constraining the output of a hashing function to a specific group

Tags: hash, data-privacy

I looked into this paper on privacy-preserving aggregation by Marc Joye and Benoit Libert (https://www.ifca.ai/fc13/proc/3-3.pdf). A key element in their scheme is a hash function defined as $$H: \mathbb{Z} \mapsto (\mathbb{Z}/N^{2}\mathbb{Z})^{*}$$ without giving an example of such a construction, which left me puzzled as it does not look like any hash function I've seen before. How would one go about constructing such a hash function, and if possible, could someone link some litterature describing such hash functions? Can regular hash functions (e.g., SHA-512) be used to construct such a hash function?

Comment: Take exponentiation module $Z_{N^2}$, it is mentioned on the first hash string on the paper...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Please bear with me for a moment in case I am misunderstanding something.

If you have $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, you would interpret this integer as a bit-string, compute the hash using a conventional hashing function (e.g., SHA-512) $y = h(x)$, interpret the output bitstring as an integer in $\mathbb{Z}_{N}$ and compute $z = (1+N)^{y}\; \mathrm{mod}\; N^{2} = 1+yN$, which guarantees $z \in (\mathbb{Z}/N^{2}\mathbb{Z})^{*}$? I guess it would also be easier to just compute the last expression, since there is no exponentiation?

Comment: AFAIK, it is $m^e \bmod Z_{n^2}$ for some $e$ as in RSA.

Comment: I've also tired of such articles that doesn't give constructions. Like one of my professor said in one time, if one say something trivial ask them to prove and see actually how hard it is.

Comment: Hehe, yes - I suppose it is obvious to the intended readership. But for a novice, this is a bit problematic, especially in cryptography, where simple misunderstandings can make the system trivial to break.

Comment: Just to clarify your idea: Would that be the whole hash? No need for a conventional hash first? If so, my follow up questions would be: 
1. If the input is $m$, then you might pick an element that is not a generator of the multiplicative group, right? Isn’t that a problem? Also, is it not trivial to find collisions by choosing $m’ = m + kN^{2}$?
2. If $m$ is just a generator of the group, and the input is $e$, this is a “one-way function” since finding the discrete logarithm is “hard”. But surely, finding a second preimage and a collision is easy? In which case – it’s not a hash right?

Comment: My next thought would be - If we followed the scheme I described previously: Would using a secure hash to generate the exponent ensure second preimage resistance and collision resistance of the overall hash?